# How to configure 'cookie::$salt' in kohana

Tags: cookies, kohana, salt

In this part of the Kohana documentation: (http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/cookies) it says I can find

```
Cookie::$salt = 'foobar';
```

In bootstrap.php.

I don't see it there.  Am I just being thick, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in the [bootstrap.php file](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.1/master/application/bootstrap.php) by default. I've added it to the file, after `Kohana::modules` and before the routes.

Comment: Added that to line 90. I changed the "foobar" to something really fubared. Ex. Cookie::$salt = '9urhkc74kws1@3fdksyYDelsicdkeakducjlwadc9#0';

Answer (score 0):

Looks like config updated in the latest version 3.3.4 (at the time of writing)

```
134 /**
135  * Cookie Salt
136  * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/cookies
137  * 
138  * If you have not defined a cookie salt in your Cookie class then
139  * uncomment the line below and define a preferrably long salt.
140  */
141 // Cookie::$salt = NULL;
142 Cookie::$salt = 'LOASWnL7A1WKQMk1JALCP1H5BMelyIPQNVdXiGsbEEVhVtyApGsFC6LyINUsDHl1';
```